# Are there any other useful computational architectures than von Neuman based ones?

Tags: turing-machines, computation-models

As far as I understand it, computation today is largely based on Turing machines implemented in von Neuman architectures. Are there other realizations of Turing machines in use or being considered theoretically that would be advantageous in any way? Or even non-Turing ones that may somehow scale? It seems to me that computation the way I learned it is always inherently based on processing steps that are sequential in nature. I figured we could at least theorize machines where processing steps are connected in some non-trivial way *during* the processing, not before and after (so parallelization would obviously not count).

*What I mean by being connected "during" processing, not "before or after":*

Processors get instructions and information about a particular component of the larger computation task. Knowing the outcome of other (perhaps parallelized) processing steps seems to me to potentially help in the computation. I don't know what that sharing of information would look like (perhaps some types of analog computers could be interpreted to be doing this?), but this sort of information bottle-neck or compartmentalization(?) seems like a limitation that I figured someone must've tried to overcome at some point.

*What I mean by useful:* Anything that could potentially speed up either computation in general or better facilitate certain algorithms. I hope that's not too vague, I don't have specific "usefulness" I'm looking for.

Comment: The Harvard architecture.

Comment: Can you expand on *`during`* `the processing, not before and after`? The ubiquity of sequentiality may be owed to the way we *communicate* about processing even more than to our mental model. I think "Shaw's" *NON-VON Architecture* even more promising than the *Connection Machine* - as a mental model, not so much as a blueprint for hardware. It may help if you define *useful*.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I added the clarifications as an edit.

Comment: Have you looked into lambda calculus? Logic programming? Worth reading is the classic Jim Backus Turing award speech, "Can Programming Be Liberated from the von Neumann Style?" http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~wael/teaching/324-03f/papers/backus.pdf

Comment: Quantum Von Neumann architecture perhaps?

Comment: I would not say that computation today is _based_ on Turing machines, whether or not implemented in von Neumann architecture, as programmes for practical purposes are hardly ever conceived in terms of Turing machines. I think instead of Turing machines as a tool to analyse what computers can and cannot do, given some very broad assumptions about how they work.